# Looking for good synonyms of "requires"

Tags: synonyms

> Writing **requires** mastering vocabulary.

I am looking to build a list of synonyms of "requires" that could substitute it in the above example, the goal being to enrich my vocabulary in my essays.

I have of course looked up dictionaries for synonyms and recurringly found candidates such as "involves", "entails", "calls for" or "demands", but they seem imperfect synonyms. Maybe I am wrong. Are there any synonyms that could work as perfect (or almost perfect) substitutes in the sentence? Thank you!

Comment: Have you searched the internet for synonyms of "requires"?

Comment: There aren't really any "synonyms" in English. And personally I think it's poor writing style to pointlessly switch between different terms that you think mean the same thing. Decide on the "best" term for your intended meaning and stick with it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for synonyms. Which are as rare as chocolate teapots, and about as much use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are cases where that's not a good strategy, such as writing SEO-sensitive content for the Internet.

Comment: @swmcdonnell: What? So we should endorse bad writing techniques just because it generates more revenue? So far as I'm concerned, most "SEO-sensitive content" is right down there with "money" as ***the root of all evil***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I wouldn't characterize using synonyms to add variety to a composition a bad writing technique. You must be independently wealthy if you think that writing content to earn money is evil.

Answer (score 2):

"**Demands**" is the best match of the words you've found; you're right that the others are weaker synonyms.

However, if you change around your sentence structure to use an adjective form:

> Mastering vocabulary is **required** for writing.

You have some more options: "**essential**," "**necessary**," "**critical**," or "**integral**" would all work well here.